# How to navigate with react native expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I know it is a basic question but when I search on the web the answer is always a single file mith multiple functions [link here for exemple](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Hello%20React%20Navigation%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.3.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.3.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.6.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.2.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fmultiple-push.js).
What I want is to use one function per file and multiple file ( I fought it would be simple like in HTML but when I look into it it seems so complicated! I only want to navigate between 2 pages!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link which you provide we only need to do the changes that we have to create new file and paste that function in new file like below

**HomeScreen.js file is looks like this**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
Const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:   'center' }}>
       <Text>Home Screen</Text>
       <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
       />
      </View>
  );
 }
 export default HomeScreen;
```

**DetailsScreen.js file is looks like this**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
Const DetailsScreen = ({ navigation }) =>  {

return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
     <Text>Details Screen</Text>
     <Button
      title="Go to Details... again"
      onPress={() => navigation.push('Details')}
      />
    </View>
   );
 }
export default DetailsScreen;
```

**And your app.js file looks like this.**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from ‘../HomeScreen’;
import DetailsScreen from ‘../DetailsScreen’
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
         <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
         <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
       </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
 );
}

export default App;
```